# bxslider fade mode does fade out but "pops" in, what did I do wrong?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, bxslider

Trying to get the bxslider to fade between images. This works fine except for the next image not fading in, instead it just appears, causing it to "blink" or "pop" in.

I am also suffering form the issue where in IE (I'm on v11) the images tile vertically as a normal UL and do not animate.

Here is my slider declaration in HTML

```
<ul class="bxslider">
          <li><img src="IMG" /></li>
          <li><img src="IMG" /></li>
          <li><img src="IMG" /></li>
          <li><img src="IMG" /></li>
        </ul>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
              mode: 'fade',
              speed: 500
            });
          });
        </script>
```

And here is the entirety of my stylesheets declarations.

```
<!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="all">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>

  <link href="js/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="rmm-css/responsivemobilemenu.css" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="rmm-js/responsivemobilemenu.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/col.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/2cols.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/3cols.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/4cols.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/5cols.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/6cols.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/7cols.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/8cols.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/9cols.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/10cols.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/11cols.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/12cols.css" media="all">
```

I've been trying to get some sort of responsive slider up and running for days now, please help.

Suggesting other sliders or methods can also help solve my problem, take note that I do not know anything about jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

by default, fadeIn/fadeout have 'pause':4000 and 'speed':500, set 'speed' to 2000 (msec) would have fadeIn performs well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and discovered I had accidentally declared two instances of bxSlider on the same group of images. 
I redid my js code to remove one of them and the problem was fixed.